# change value in cell if it not already set

Tags: excel, vba

Why this code not work?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Target.Value) <> 14 Then
            Target.Value = Format(Now(), ["yyyymmddhhmmss"])
            Target.NumberFormat = "0"
        Else
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .Undo
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
        End If
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(18)) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Target.Value) <> 10 Then
            Target.Value = Format(Date, ["yyyy.mm.dd"])
        Else
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .Undo
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I need to change value in cell if it not already set (I check for string len), so if value is set I need to prevent this value from changes by this macros and let changing only manually.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by using `Application.EnableEvents = False` before changing any values and then `Application.EnableEvents = True` before exiting. By changing the value(s), you are triggering another event that runs on top of the original and may attempt to undo what you started.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Columns(1), Columns(18))) Is Nothing Then
        Dim tmp As Variant
        tmp = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
            If Len(Target.Value) <> 14 Then
                Target.Value = Format(Now(), ["yyyymmddhhmmss"])
            End If
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(18)) Is Nothing Then
            If Len(Target.Value) <> 10 Then
                Target.Value = Format(Date, ["yyyy.mm.dd"])
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The other hole in your logic was checking the current **Target** value's length. You needed to undo first to see what the value was **before** something new was typed in.

Comment: tbh, I am unclear on why you are time stamping the same cell as your new value. I found the hole in your logic but I do not understand why you timestamp column A when you just typed a value into column A.

Comment: because i need unique value on each row. but after seting this value i can unintentionally change this value, so i need to prevent changing this unique value

Comment: I think I get it now. See above. I think your primary concern now will be changes to more than one cell; e.g. when Target represents several cells (like a paste operation).